# How do you dynamically wrap a specific table row in a form?

Tags: javascript, html

So basically I have a table, and when the "edit" button is clicked on a specific row, the user should have option to edit any of the columns in the row and then submit the changes through POST.

The table is initialized like this with data from a DB :

```
{% for r in result %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form onsubmit="editBook()">
                <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
            </form>
        </td>
        <form action='/editBook' method='POST'> >
        <td class="isbn" id="isbn">{{r.itemID}}</td>
        <td class="ttl" id="ttl"> {{r.title}}</td>
        <td class="avail" id="avail"> {{r.numAvailable}}</td>
        </form>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Then I have JS that gets the value of what was initially in the column and places that as a default in an input box that the user can edit before confirming changes (the first part works successful for what I want it to do):

```
bookTable.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    item = event.target.closest("tr");

    itemID = item.querySelector(".isbn").textContent;
    title = item.querySelector(".ttl").textContent;
    avail = item.querySelector(".avail").textContent;
});

function editBook() {
    item.querySelector(".isbn").innerHTML = "<input type='text' value=" + itemID + ">";
    item.querySelector(".ttl").innerHTML = "<input type='text' value=" + title + ">";
    item.querySelector(".avail").innerHTML = "<input type='text' value=" + avail + "> <input type='submit' value='Confirm'>";

}
```

So I do have a form with input and submission, but nothing happens when the submit button is clicked. I suspect it is due to the way I create the table in the first place through a loop (I know those rows shouldn't have id's since they won't be unique), but I'm not sure how else to reference the specific row. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is what I hope help you to uniquely reference a specific row**

1. use the index from the loop to make each row unique, by appending it 
   to the id of each row.
2. pass the index to `editBook()` function on submit, so you can use it 
   to query the specific row

```js
bookTable.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    item = event.target.closest("tr");

    itemID = item.querySelector(".isbn").textContent;
    title = item.querySelector(".ttl").textContent;
    avail = item.querySelector(".avail").textContent;
});

function editBook(index) {
    item.querySelector(`#isbn-${index}`).innerHTML = "<input type='text' value=" + itemID + ">";
    item.querySelector(`#ttl-${index}`).innerHTML = "<input type='text' value=" + title + ">";
    item.querySelector(`#avail-${index}`).innerHTML = "<input type='text' value=" + avail + "> <input type='submit' value='Confirm'>";

}
```

```html
{% for r in result %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form onsubmit="editBook(r.index)">
                <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
            </form>
        </td>
        <form action='/editBook' method='POST'> >
        <td class="isbn" id="isbn-{{r.index}}">{{r.itemID}}</td>
        <td class="ttl" id="ttl-{{r.index}}"> {{r.title}}</td>
        <td class="avail" id="avail-{{r.index}}"> {{r.numAvailable}}</td>
        </form>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, this makes sense in theory but it's working properly.
    id="isbn-{{r.index}}" 
is not properly applying the index, any ideas to fix?

Comment: Sorry Avalon. I'm not familiar with the scripting language you're using inside the template. May be this could work, I'm not sure. id="{% 'isbn-' r.index %}

Answer (score 0):

you ll have to keep hidden inputs in td and once the user clicks on edit change their display property from none to inline and hide the initial content and then make an ajax request once he is done editing.